# Splitting String Arrays into Groups

Tags: c#, arrays, string, grouping

There is a string [] yield that can contain N count data. I have defined 15 count to be an example.

I want to divide these data into 6 groups.However, I cannot load the last remaining items into the array.

Where am I making a mistake?

```
string[] tags = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"};

double tagLength = (int)Math.Floor(tags.Length / (double)6);

for (int i = 0; i <= tagLength-1; i++)
{
    string[] groupArrays = new string[6];
    Array.Copy(tags, i * 6, groupArrays, 0, 6);            
}
```

The output i see

[0] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

[1] = {7,8,9,10,11,12}

---

Should be output

[0] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

[1] = {7,8,9,10,11,12}

[2] = {13,14,15}

Comment: Do you mean "groups of 6", or actually 6 groups?

Comment: You know `IEnumerable<T>.Take()`? Should give you up to six strings

Comment: @KindaOkProgrammer  groups of 6

Comment: I wrote it wrong, I'm sorry. @john

[0] = {1,2,3,4,5,6}

[1] = {7,8,9,10,11,12}

[2] = {13,14,15}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest changing your code to calculate the number of groups you need to this:

```
int groups = (count / groupSize);
bool hasPartialGroup = count % groupSize != 0;
if (hasPartialGroup)
{
    ++groups;
}
```

The result of the first line will be integer division, so 15 / 6 will result in 2. We then see if there is a remainder using the [remainder operator (`%`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/arithmetic-operators#remainder-operator-): `count % groupSize`. If its result isn't 0, then there is a remainder, and we have a partial group, so we have to account for that.

So for `groups = 15` and `groupSize = 6`, we'll get `count = 3`. For `groups = 12` and `groupSize = 6`, we'll get `count = 2`, etc.

Fixing your code to use this, it might look like:

```
string[] tags = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"};

int count = tags.Length;
const int groupSize = 6;
int groups = (count / groupSize);
bool hasPartialGroup = count % groupSize != 0;
if (hasPartialGroup)
{
    ++groups;
}

for (int i = 0; i < groups; i++)
{
    // you can't copy beyond the end of the array so we have to choose between the remaining ungrouped items and the group size
    int currentGroupSize = Math.Min(tags.Length - i*groupSize, groupSize);
    // I'm assuming for a partial group you only want this to be as big as the number of items.
    // If you want it to always be 6 then change new string[currentGroupSize] to new string[groupSize] and you should be OK.
    string[] groupArrays = new string[currentGroupSize];
    Array.Copy(tags, i * groupSize, groupArrays, 0, currentGroupSize);         
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", groupArrays));
}
```

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/TWDOF90810) // [Example with fixed group size](https://rextester.com/GRVS41191)

---

Alternatively, you could create a batching helper method:

```
private static IEnumerable<T[]> BatchItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    var collection = new List<T>(batchSize);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        collection.Add(item);
        if (collection.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return collection.ToArray();
            collection.Clear();
        }
    }

    if (collection.Count > 0)
    {
        yield return collection.ToArray();
    }
}
```

This will collect `batchSize` number items together and then return one group at a time. You can read about how this works with `yield return` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield).

Usage:

```
string[] tags = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"};
List<string[]> batchedTags = BatchItems(tags, 6).ToList();
```

This will result in 3 string arrays, containing `1,2,3,4,5,6`, `7,8,9,10,11,12`, and `13,14,15`.

You could also make this into an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

[Try it online](https://rextester.com/CZTK39947)

Comment: Thank you very much @John. I understood where I made the mistake and applied the solution method. You are great. Thank you so much for your help.

Thank you very much to my other friends who answered. We solved the problem.

Stay healthy

Answer (score 0):

Because you use Math.Floor(...). You should use Math.Ceiling(...) instead.

```
(int)Math.Floor(15d / 6d) // returns 2 >> 2 groups.
(int)Math.Ceiling(15d / 6d) // returns 3 >> 3 groups.
```

Beware though, you will get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException in Array.Copy, since index 3 * 6 does not exist. You will have to find a way around that.

One possible solution:

```
    string[] tags = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };

    double tagLength = (int)Math.Ceiling(tags.Length / (double)6);

    for (int i = 0; i <= tagLength - 1; i++)
    {
        int arrLength = (i + 1) * 6 <= tags.Length ? 6 : tags.Length % 6;
        string[] groupArrays = new string[arrLength]; // or six if you always want a length of 6
        Array.Copy(tags, i * 6, groupArrays, 0, arrLength);
    }
```

Or using Linq:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < (int)Math.Ceiling(tags.Length / 6d); i++)
        {
            string[] groupArrays = tags.Skip(i * 6).Take(6).ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: This will throw an error if length of tags % 6!= 0. Id suggest doing my solution if you aren't sure if all the groups can be 6 elements long.

Comment: Correct, I tested myself to double check. The example given should handle that now.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean why you are not getting groups of 6, the reason for this is that you are flooring the `length of tags / 6`. So, if the last group has the length of less that 6, it won't get added. Add this to the end:

```
if (tags.Length%6!=0) { string[] groupArrays = tags[i..tags.Length] } // You can do this manually.
```

Answer (score 0):

As said before, it's because you use Math.Floor(). Use either Math.Ceiling or remove the -1 from i<= taglength - 1.

Array.Copy will still produce errors when you're tags aren't an exact multiple of 6.
Below code should do the trick and won't produce an error

```
string[] tags = { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15" };

            int baselength = 6;
            double tagLength = (int)Math.Floor(tags.Length / (double)6);
            int length = baselength;
            for (int i = 0; i <= tagLength; i++)
            {
                string[] groupArrays = new string[baselength];
                if (i == tagLength)
                    length = ((i + 1) * length) - tags.Length;

                if(length > 0 && length < baselength)
                    Array.Copy(tags, i * 6, groupArrays, 0, length);
            }
```